# Ubuntu login loops, unable to access root, sudo command throwing error

Tags: permissions, login, sudo, root, authentication

Ubuntu desktop version is 20.04LTS.
I used a usb to make a bootable file.Then I see usb is not permitted by roots then I have done a little bit change on home folder that is opend properties and select the option of write and delete for all.

1.**I can't login to ubuntu though password is correct**

2.**If I want to perform any sudo command then I get it**

> sudo: error in /etc/sudo.conf, line 0 while loading plugin
> 'sudoers_policy'
> sudo: /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so must only be writable
> by owner
> sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins

3.**If I use "su _" command then I get**

> authentication failed

4. 

> I can't do anything as a root user.

5.**Internet connection not working and also I don't see the icon of wireless**

I don't know what to do.I can't open laptop and perform any of task.If anyone understand this please help me...

Comment: Hello. What version of Ubuntu? What did you do this did not happen on its own. You have run some commends deleted something what? Based on the info in this question there is only one solution reinstall.

Comment: You've not provided any OS/product/release details; however any error in the `sudoers` file is treated as the *end-of-file* which cause it to be stop being read, meaning any entries after the error will be ignored (and if it's file permissions; then the whole file maybe ignored).  FYI:  You maybe able to fix your issue via *live* media; but I don't know your system details so this could also be incorrect; adjust for your *unstated* system.

Comment: I am new user of ubuntu.I didn't have prior experience.I don't know how it happened.Sir if you feel that I am really in trouble then plase give me a chance to talk with you via whatsapp ...

Comment: You didn't say if it was Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop, or Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server.. but either way I'd boot *live* media (eg. Ubuntu 20.04 LTS installation media & select "*Try Ubuntu*"), mount your installed systems partitions & correct the ownership using *live* media (ie. return it to what it should be).  If done correctly I'd expect you to have `sudo` rights when you next boot normally IF that was your only issue.

Comment: Sir I haven't tried it before so I don't understand that you want to tell me...

Comment: You've given no clues as to what caused the issue; what I provided was a clue on how I'd fix the issue I see from your description (*which yeah wasn't newbie helpful*) but if you used a `sudo chown -R` or `sudo chmod -R` type of command that modified that file; that issue is only ONE of MANY problems you have, where the re-install @David suggested will be faster... Changes in your $HOME folder would not change what you describe; but sorry I'm unwilling to give *newbie* details on fixing that one issue given it's likely not your real issue as you've given no explanation of cause..

Comment: You can wait for others to read & given their advice/opinions (*what I provided; heh - someone may provide an answer I'm not seeing too*!), but if you're talking about a Ubuntu Desktop system, you can re-install the system rather quickly & fix package problems, plus user permissions issues like this in system directories... I'm involved in QA (*Quality Assurance*) with *flavors* of Ubuntu, and re-install my systems instead of performing normal upgrades as it performs a QA-test install, and gives me the latest packages; all without touching my user files, and re-installing my added packages too